# can i have shopping carts without plugin?

Tags: e-commerce

can I have a shopping cart in word press without plugins?
and if yes how ? hard code or there is some easy way?
I don't trust plugins these days . but if you guys know any trusted plugin for a shopping cart please let me know, I have tried so many hard code options but all have some problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly code your own shopping cart - but ultimately that code should live inside a custom plugin (or plugin functionality housed in a custom theme). So the short answer is "no" - one way or another you need to write or use a plugin.

Please note that plugin recommendations are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this stack. But [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/) is now an Automattic property - it is developed and supported by corporate stewards of WordPress. It's fairly robust, but if you have been coding your own cart you may find that it is too heavy for your needs.

Comment: thanks brh, woocommerce it is then

Comment: trusting WC? that sounds like a mistake :) So many years and they still have a horrible DB scheme

Comment: I haven't worked much with ecommerce plugins - I do recall having a miserable time with Woo, but it was the only thing I had off the top of my head which I thought might assuage the skepticism of the plugin ecosystem

Comment: what do u suggest then Mark Kaplun ?